# Twilio: Is it possible to disable incoming text messages?

Tags: twilio

I am new to Twillio. I just bought a number and I am using API to send text messages through that number. But the recipient is able to reply back to that number. How can I disable incoming text messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable text messaging completely for a number, but you cannot selectively disable incoming texts or texts from a specific number.

See this for more information:
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-sms-on-my-twilio-phone-number

Comment: Updated link: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181648-Is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-SMS-on-my-Twilio-phone-number-